# a matlab program computing the powers of 1/6

Tags: matlab

the powers of 1/6 are computed using a recursive function, I tried to program that on matlab and here is my program

```
 function [V]=meth1(n)
 V(1)=1;
 V(2)=1/6;
       if n>=3
          V(n)=(37/6)*meth1(n-1)-meth1(n-2);
       end
 V=V(n);
 end
```

My problem is that when I want to compute the 5th power for instance I get the 4th power instead ! I tried to fix it but the recursive function makes it very hard ! If you have any idea or hints, I'll be grateful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be good if you also updated your question with examples of your input and the expected output.

Comment: you say `V(1) = 1`, but i think it is `V(0) = 1`, and as matlab indexes start from 0, you should add `1` to `n` when you enter the funciton, like `n = n+1`.

Comment: NO, the prevoious comment is completely wrong, Matlab indexes start from `1`. Please don't post if you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I can't see this recursion ever ending. When does the recursion stop?

Comment: yes, i thought it right, wrote it wrong. matlab indexes start from 1, that's why you have to add 1 to n, or you will never have `meth1(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would implement the recursive function. (N must remain less than 500).

```
function [V]=meth1(n)
if n == 0
    V = 1;
elseif n == 1
    V = 1/6;
else
    V = (37/6)*meth1(n-1)-meth1(n-2)
 end

 end
```

Comment: Why would you put restrictions on `n`?

Comment: if by restriction you mean the n<500 is because MATLAB will stop recursive function going deeper that 500 i think.

Comment: The first programm works but the second one dosen't it shows the error message : ??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Comment: yea sorry, the second code is wrong adding `n=n+1`  makes it and infinite loop. code removed.